# PHP Multidimensional Array foreach - do not repeat common value

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Here is my array:

```
    $tabs = Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [primaryTabID] => 001
        [subtabID] => 
        [parent_tab] => 
        [primaryName] => Tab1
        [subName] => 
        [BStatus] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [primaryTabID] => 002
        [subtabID] => 013
        [parent_tab] => 002
        [primaryName] => Tab2
        [subName] => SubTab2-1
        [BStatus] => A
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [primaryTabID] => 003
        [subtabID] => 015
        [parent_tab] => 003
        [primaryName] => Tab3
        [subName] => SubTab3-1
        [BStatus] => A
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [primaryTabID] => 003
        [subtabID] => 016
        [parent_tab] => 003
        [primaryName] => Tab3
        [subName] => Subtab3-2
        [BStatus] => A
    )
  )
```

The output I'm looking for lists each Primary Tab name only once, and then if it has subtabs each one is listed after the primary tab, like this:

Output:

```
    001 -> Tab1
    002 -> Tab2
        013 -> SubTab2-1
    003 -> Tab3
        015 -> SubTab3-1
        016 -> SubTab3-2
```

The nesting of foreach statements and if-else has me completely befuddled.

Comment: I don't understand how you want to SubTabs to be stored. From the Output you are displayed, it seems you want an associative array, however is the 013 -> SubTab2 an array inside an array together with 002 -> Tab2?

Comment: I'm actually echoing them out into a table, so it's misleading to think of my output as an array (sorry about that.)  My code echoes out the primary tab in the first column, then each subtab (if it has any) in the second column.

Comment: What do you mean by echo in table? Is this MySql table? Post your code to echo in table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your array like this...

```
$out = array();
foreach($tabs as $tab) {
    if(!empty($tab['primaryTabID']))
        $out[$tab['primaryTabID']]['main'] = $tab['primaryName'];           
    if($tab['primaryTabID'] == $tab['parent_tab'])
        $out[$tab['primaryTabID']][$tab['subtabID']] = $tab['subName'];
}
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($out);
```

Then, process it (output is the same with what you displayed above..

```
    foreach($out as $key => $tab) {
        if(count($tab) == 1) {
            echo $key . " -> " .$tab['main']."\n";
        } else {
            foreach($tab as $subKey => $sub) {
                if($subKey == "main")
                    echo $key . " -> " .$tab['main']."\n";
                else
                    echo "\t".$subKey . " -> " .$sub."\n";
            }
        }
    }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
001 -> Tab1
002 -> Tab2
    013 -> SubTab2-1
003 -> Tab3
    015 -> SubTab3-1
    016 -> Subtab3-2
```

Comment: That does it!  Thanks severinolorillajr!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

**Data:**

```
$tabs = array(
    0 => array(
        'primaryTabID' => '001',
        'subtabID' => '',
        'parent_tab' => '',
        'primaryName' => 'Tab1',
        'subName' => '',
        'BStatus' => '',
    ),
    1 => array(
        'primaryTabID' => '002',
        'subtabID' => '013',
        'parent_tab' => '002',
        'primaryName' => 'Tab2',
        'subName' => 'SubTab2-1',
        'BStatus' => 'A',
    ),
    2 => array(
        'primaryTabID' => '003',
        'subtabID' => '015',
        'parent_tab' => '003',
        'primaryName' => 'Tab3',
        'subName' => 'SubTab3-1',
        'BStatus' => 'A',
    ),
    3 => array(
        'primaryTabID' => '003',
        'subtabID' => '016',
        'parent_tab' => '003',
        'primaryName' => 'Tab3',
        'subName' => 'Subtab3-2',
        'BStatus' => 'A',
    ),
);
```

**Code:**

```
$new_tabs = array();

foreach($tabs as $key => $value) {
    if (!array_key_exists ($value['primaryTabID'], $new_tabs)) {
        $new_tabs[$value['primaryTabID']] = array('primaryName' => $value['primaryName']);
    }
    if (!empty($value['subtabID'])) {
        $new_tabs[$value['primaryTabID']]['children'][$value['subtabID']] = $value['subName'];
    }
}

foreach($new_tabs as $key => $value) {
    echo '<p>'.$key.' -> '.$value['primaryName'].'</p>';
    if (!empty($value['children'])) {
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach($value['children'] as $s_key => $s_value) {
            echo '<li>'.$s_key.' -> '.$s_value.'</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
001 -> Tab1

002 -> Tab2

    013 -> SubTab2-1

003 -> Tab3

    015 -> SubTab3-1
    016 -> Subtab3-2
```

Comment: This also works, thank you Kostas.  I had already checked severinolorillajr's solution because it was there first and it works.  Your solution works equally well.

Answer (score 0):

```
$newArray = array();

foreach ($tab as $elements)
{
  array_push($newArray, 
    array(
      $elements['primaryTabID'] => $elements['primaryName'], 
      $elements['subtabID'] => $elements['subName']
    )
  );
}
```

Let me know if that was what you were looking for! If it wasn't tell me what is different because I might have misunderstood how you wanted the Sub Tabs to be located in relation to the Primary Tabs

Comment: Your array repeats the primaryTabID each time it is found.  The part I'm having difficulty with is getting the primaryTabID to only show once, and then the subtabID's to show under their parent tab (a primaryTab.)

Comment: @EotS No, I am inserting a new primery tab, not repeating the same one. $elements is different for each iteration of the for loop. WHEN you say "under" what does that specifically mean? do you want a multidimentional array or just 1 array, with the subtab to be directly under it?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($tabs as $tab)
{
    $key = array_search($tab['primaryName'], array_column($newArray, 'primaryTabID'));
    if($key)
    {
        $newArray[$key]['subtabID'][] = $tab['subName'];
    }
    else
    {
      array_push($newArray,  array( 'primaryTabID' => $tab['primaryName'], $tab['subtabID'] => array($tab['subName'])) );
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($newArray);
echo "</pre>";
```